# Pyspark filtering to keep unique rows only

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Here is some pyspark code that creates a dataframe with a schema.

I would like to filter or drop rows where the index content already exists in a previous row.  So that the content in either the first_index or second_index is unique and only appears once in the dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType

two_index_schema = StructType([
            StructField("first_index", IntegerType(), True),
            StructField("second_index", IntegerType(), True),
        ])

df = self.spark.createDataFrame([(2, 8), (1, 8), (2, 10), (1, 10)], schema=two_index_schema)

# prints the dataframe to screen.
df.show()
```

The correct output result rows after the deduplication, filtering or dropping rows would be like this.
[(2, 8), (1, 10)]

This is correct because the 2nd row has an 8 in the second index which appears in the first rows second index aswell.  So, the second row is dropped.  In the third row the 2 in the first index has already appeared in the first index of the first row, so the third row gets removed.  Leaving just the first row and the fourth row in the dataframe.

I have tried variations around these two approaches, but not yielded what I want:-

```
df_deduplicated = self.a_df.dropDuplicates(subset=["first_index", "second_index"])
```

```
df_deduplicated = self.a_df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("first_index", "second_index"))) \
        #     .filter("row_num = 1").drop("row_num")
```

Wondering if someone with experience of Spark or SQL might be able to help guide me in the right direction ?